# How to connect Llama-Index Chat Engine to Slack?

Tags: chatbot, slack-api, llama-index

I have a chatbot currently in slack that's integrated with llama-index's `Query Engine`. It will ask a question and will reply based on the document I fed it to.

The problem with this is that it doesn't have any memory of the previous questions that I have asked.

Sample Convo:

```
Me: What did Paul Graham do after YC?
Bot: Paul Graham's next step in his career after his involvement with Y Combinator was to take up painting. He spent most of the rest of 2014 painting and then in March 2015 he started working on Lisp again.

Me: What about after that?
Bot: After the current situation, the narrator resumes painting and experimenting with a new kind of still life. He also resumes his old life in New York, now that he is rich. He is able to take taxis and eat in restaurants, which is exciting for a while. He also starts to connect with other people who are trying to paint in New York.
```

The bot's state will reset every question.

I've found a solution in llama-index's documentation and it's the `Chat Engine`
Which will do this:

```
Me: What did Paul Graham do after YC?
Bot: Paul Graham's next step in his career after his involvement with Y Combinator was to take up painting. He spent most of the rest of 2014 painting and then in March 2015 he started working on Lisp again.

Me: What about after that?
Bot: Paul Graham spent the rest of 2015 writing essays and working on the new dialect of Lisp he called Arc. He also looked for an apartment to buy and started to plan a second still life painting from the same objects.
```

Which takes into consideration the previous questions.

The problem is that I don't know how to set it up so that it retains the `Chat Engine` in Slack. How do I do it?